# NG-Grid + Flot chart only redraw when resizing browser window

Tags: angularjs, draw, flot, ng-grid

I populate my ng-grid table with data I retrieve from Parse.com.  The table starts off blank as it waits to get the data from Parse.  After I get the data and pipe it to the corresponding variable, I have to resize the browser window to get the updated data in the table.

Similarly, I send some new data to my Flot chart and the chart will only redraw after I resize the browser window.

Comment: You need to show your code, especially the event handling for resize and data update.

Comment: You need to show your code, particularly the function responsible receiving the Parse data. Are you redrawing your chart after receiving data?